# How to replace the string using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, object

I have the following string and object,

```
const str = "$(role.name) is $(role) team. $(role.name) started his role as $(role)"

const obj = {
  role: 'Dev',
  'role.name': 'Foo',
}

const expected = "Foo is Dev team.Foo started his role as Dev"
```

How to using regex ?

My regex ,

```
const data = str.match(/\$\((.*?)\)/g)
```

Comment: The key is in the title: `replace`

Comment: Does it have to be `regex`?

Comment: It might be easier to start with the object, and then build the output with [a template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: See [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](/q/1408289/4642212), [How to replace multiple keywords by corresponding keywords with the `replace` method?](/q/14013223/4642212), [Can ES6 template literals be substituted at runtime (or reused)?](/q/30003353/4642212), and [Defer execution for ES6 Template Literals](/q/22607806/4642212). Use template strings, or use an approach with [`replace`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a non-greedy regex and a function as the second argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of matching, you should replace. As you already have the capture group, you can check if the group 1 exists as a key in the obj.

Note that in your `expected` there is not space here `team.Foo`

```js
const str = "$(role.name) is $(role) team. $(role.name) started his role as $(role)"
const regex = /\$\(([^()]*)\)/g;
const obj = {
  role: 'Dev',
  'role.name': 'Foo',
}
const result = str.replace(regex, (m, g1) => obj.hasOwnProperty(g1) ? obj[g1] : m);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good use of `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, it has been closed unfortunately, could you help voting to reopen it? I think it is a pretty clear question.

Comment: Yes I will vote to open it

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the replace() method with a regular expression pattern.

Here's an example of how you can achieve the desired replacement using the given string and object:

```js
const str = "$(role.name) is $(role) team. $(role.name) started his role as $(role)";

const obj = {
  role: 'Dev',
  'role.name': 'Foo',
};

// Create a regular expression pattern to match the placeholders
const pattern = /\$\(([\w.]+)\)/g;

// Replace the placeholders with the corresponding values from the object
const result = str.replace(pattern, (match, key) => obj[key]);

console.log(result);
// Output: "Foo is Dev team. Foo started his role as Dev"
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for info on formatting your answer.

Comment: Hi IGOR, welcome to Stack Overflow, for your first answer that was great, up-vote from me.  Like pointed out by 001, it was just your formatting, the comments were easy to understand etc.   If you have simple Javascript like this using code snippet `<>` icon in editor you can paste code here and it becomes runnable for everyone to try.  I've done this bit for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

For a none `regex` solution, `replaceAll` is nice and simple.

> Please note, as pointed out in comments, although this will work in most cases, be aware that if a
> replace on one of the passes ends up creating another valid tag in
> later passes, these will get replaced too.  As such I would say the
> cleanest solution is the `regex` and the `(match, key)` callback.
> I'll leave this answer here as it still might be useful for others to
> see.

```js
const str = "$(role.name) is $(role) team. $(role.name) started his role as $(role)"

const obj = {
  role: 'Dev',
  'role.name': 'Foo',
}

const fillTemplate = (str, obj) => {
  let ret = str;
  for ([k,v] of Object.entries(obj)) 
    ret = ret.replaceAll(`$(${k})`, v);
  return ret;
}

console.log(fillTemplate(str, obj));
```

Comment: Note that this will continue replacing the `$(` and `)` delimiters if they occur in the substituted substring; the result also depends on the enumeration order of objects, which isn’t supposed to be relied on. With `const str = "$(a)c$(b)", obj = { a: "$(", b: ")", c: "x" };`, the result will be `"x"`; but with `const str = "$(a)c$(b)", obj = { a: "$(", c: "x", b: ")" };`, it will be `"$(c)"`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon  Yeah, that's a good point.  Looking at the `regex` example with the `(match, key)` is way better.  I'll put a comment in answer on that bit.  Cheers..